# Add additional info to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the best way to store one single additional attribute at an arraylist?
Let's say I pass an ArrayList of Objects to a method and get an ArrayList back with an additional flag.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
//fill
list = myMethod(list);
```

And I want to get a boolean for each Object, but I don't want to store it directly in the object.
So data before myMethod: Apple, Banana, Grapefruit
After myMethod: Apple=>true, Banana=>false, Grapefruit=>false.

How can I store that additional attribute when not in the object? What is the best datatype? ArrayList can not do that, right?

Comment: Why don't you want to store it directly in the object? It's the best way.

Comment: You might was well make your Object include a boolean instance variable.

Comment: make a method public boolean checkCheckity(MyObject o) and just call it.

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with the object. Basically the myMethod diplays the objects to the user and gets for each object a user input (true or false). Based on this boolean variable, the main program does for each object some stuff. However the user input is for only this decision, so storing it at the object, would be odd.

Comment: How about using Map<MyObject, Boolean>?

Comment: @AsierAranbarri what a name for a method :)

Comment: @whoAmI if `MyObject` can't be modified and doesn't implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods, the `Map` alternative won't do it.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza It doesn't have to. Unless it has some specific and important equal related issue, Object.equals should be enough. And why does MyObject need to be modified when used as Map key?

Comment: @freakout it's not *odd*, that's how you should handle the data. As posted in my answer, if you can't (or don't want to) extend this class then make a wrapper of it. Remember that you will need to store the `boolean` flag (or any other additional data) anywhere, it won't be magically stored *in the fly*.

Comment: @whoAmI some `Map` implementations like `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` uses both `equals` and `hashCode` methods to identify the key objects. Also, if you override `equals` method, *is generally necessary to override the hashCode method*. Refer to [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) javadoc.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I didn't say overriding it. Use Object.equals and Object.hashcode is good enough for Map. And you didn't answer - why do you need to implement it inside MyObject?

Comment: @whoAmI have you used a custom class as key in a `Map` to begin with? By the way, check PaulBellora's answer.

Comment: @whoAmI and you didn't realize it that? Then you should have been lucky enough to never use the same object twice in your map.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza It doesn't matter if you use different objects as different. And what about the modified problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom wrapper around Object that has a field of type object and a boolean field. This is the best solution as you will be able to choose a meaningful name for the field. 
Alternatively you can use the built-in class Pair and create a `List<Pair<MyObject, Bool>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class with a `List<MyObject>` field and a `List<Boolean>` field whose elements are flags parallel to every `MyObject` added in your `List<MyObject>`. Since this is too cumbersome, just add the boolean flag in `MyObject`. If you can't modify the class, extend it and add the `boolean` flag in your `ExtendedMyObject extends MyObject` class. If you can't extend it, make a wrapper class of `MyObject` that has a `MyObject` field and the `boolean` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You could separately maintain a [`Set<MyObject>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) - membership in the `Set` would correspond to a `true` value for that object.

Assuming you used a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), you would need to ensure `MyObject` implemented [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29). An alternative would be uniquely identifying each `MyObject` with a `String`, `Long`, etc. and maintaining a `Set` of those IDs.

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the ArrayList and give them a new property. For example:

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

    private boolean value;

    public boolean isValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

there you can have all the features from the ArrayList and you have an additinal boolean field.

**EDIT:**

If your `Boolean` value has nothing to do with the Originalobject, why not just write a Wrapperclass? There are 2 possibilities to resolve this:

1. extend your Baseclass `MyObject`
2. Write a new class with 2 properties, one for the `boolean` and the other your instance of `MyObject`

Comment: Believe me, this isn't the best approach. By the way, you're just setting a boolean flag to all the elements in the array, not for every element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just *returning* a Map with the source object (or name if unique) mapped to the boolean value.

```
 Map<MyObject,Boolean> result = myMethod(list);
```

or, if name is unique:

```
 Map<String,Boolean> result = myMethod(list);

 for (MyObject item : list) {
     Boolean result = result.get(item.getName());
     if (result) {
         ...
     }
 }
```

If:

- `MyObject` doesn't implement `#hashCode` (so you may get missed hashes for equal objects)
- name isn't unique or
- if `result` were more complex than a Boolean,

then I'd create a wrapper that wraps a MyObject with a *result* and return a `List<MyObjectResult>`.

Edit: BTW, I think you're right not to include the Boolean field on `MyObject` if it is not really a part of that object's state - i.e. if it's a transient result of some operation.